# Return object typed with generic class type

Tags: java, generics

The code below contains a getter to a Set of objects with class T:

```
public class Cube <T extends State> {

   private Set<T> states = new HashSet<>();

   public Set<T> getStates() {
      return states;
   }

}
```

Which seemed to me the valid way to return a the Set of states. However, it returns a set of Objects instead. Trying to use:

```
Cube<DestinationState> cube = new Cube<>();
Set<DestinationState> set = cube.getStates();
```

Yields a compile error on the second line:

```
Error:(187, 61) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to nl.gijspeters.pubint.graph.state.DestinationState
```

State is a generic interface with multiple implementation classes (among which DestinationState) and subinterfaces.

This may very well be a duplicate question (as it seems quite basic), however, I was not able to find the answer.

Comment: Change `new Cube();` to `new Cube<>();`

Comment: Typo in question, this is the case in the actual code. Fixed it.

Comment: Just tried your code in my "Playground" project, no compile errors, though

Comment: You're correct, It was an error somewhere hidden in the rest of my code. I thought I double-checked everything before asking, but alas. This question is irrelevant/invalid, can I just delete it?

Answer (score 1):

by default `T` is replaced with `Object` so this is type inference based on the target so try this

```
Set<DestinationState> set = cube<DestinationState>.getStates();
```